# i am unable to change background color of label of radgrid on the basis of "if condition"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, radgrid

i am working on radgrid in asp.net.i take label in the radgrid for display status of person.i want that if ststus is "availabe" the backgroung color of label is green and if status is "Not Availabe" then backround color is red.i try it by javascript but i am unable to access each record of the grid.

[image]
the Html code is:

```
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn  DataField="Editor_status" HeaderText="Editor_status" ReadOnly="true">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Editor_status"   runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Editor_status")%>' BackColor="SkyBlue" Font-Size="14px" CssClass= "badge badge-pill  hvr-grow  badge-success" ></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

i tried access the label "Editor_status" by javascript by folowing  way:

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var a = document.getElementById("Editor_status").innerText
        function myFunction() {
            if (a == "Available") {
                window.alert("avlble");
            }
            else {
                window.alert("not avlble");
            }
        }
</script>
```

but by this way no alert is display..i am weak in javascript ,so don't mind my initial level question....u also answer me in vb.net or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped the if-else-block inside a function, which won't ever get called unless **you** call it.

Try this instead:

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var a = document.getElementById("Editor_status").innerText
            if (a == "Available") {
                window.alert("avlble");
            }
            else {
                window.alert("not avlble");
            }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The above code snippet merely checks the .innerText property. Do you get an alert dialog now?

Comment: if i get alert.... then i replace background color on the place of alert...but now i want get an alert..exactly...

Comment: So you don't get an alert or an alert of **not avlble**?

Answer (score 0):

```
      <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
               var a =document.getElementById('<%=Editor_status.ClientID%>').innerText; 
    myFunction(a);
    });
                function myFunction(a) {
                    if (a == "Available") {
                        window.alert("avlble");
                    }
                    else {
                        window.alert("not avlble");
                    }
                }
        </script>


Do this it will call the function on document ready
```

Comment: i tried it but it is not working.i take alert before(variable declaration) "var a" line it show alert and one alert after this line and it is not show alert.   my code is 
          
             window.alert("before");
             var a = document.getElementById("Editor_status1").innerText;
              window.alert("after");
               after alert is not display...

Comment: var a =document.getElementById('<%=Editor_status.ClientID%>').innerText;

Comment: use this line and check

Comment: syntax error orrured.... 'Editor_status' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: i get the problem..if i take simple label and keep id="editor_status1" then var a access the label....in my case label is inside the radgrid and  it is not accessed....now the problem is that how i can access radgrid label...